# Properties files in Grails

Tags: grails, properties, locale

there are some messages.properties files in grails app for many locales and in every file the chars is in corrent utf-8 encoding. but when I create a new properties file (e.g. messages_az.properties for Azeri locale) there are an hex codes appears in it. what i can do to resolve this. maybe I must do some config in my app

Comment: How are you creating these files? Which editor/IDE are you using? I once had an issue with creating files with a byte-order mark (BOM) that text editors don't display, but would appear in the hex and would actually break the build (because the compiler doesn't like the unknown BOM symbol). Might be something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your IDE is configured to encode property files automatically.